# Is there a shortcut for wrapping a statement with system.out.println in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

It appears to me that sometimes I want to print the values of a variable, so I repeat the following actions:

1. write sout TAB (shortcut for system.out.println)
2. write the variable name inside the function

Is it possible in IntelliJ to wrap a variable with a function, using keyboard shortcuts only?

Comment: This would only make sense if you had the variable on a line by itself.  Better to run the code in a dubugger and look at its value in a watch window.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

In Intellij Idea 13.1, there is a shortcut way called "postfix code completion".

So, to wrap an expression, object or variable with `System.out.println`, you simply write its name, put a dot then write sout, then hit tab. So, for example:

```
new MyObject().sout + <tab>
```

will be converted to

```
System.out.println(new MyObject())
```

More examples:

```
"Hello World!".sout

int myVariable = 5;
myVariable.sout
```

You can get more information about postfix completions on this page:
http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2014/03/postfix-completion/

Answer (score 3):

You can it with defining a Live Template (configurable in `Settings->Live Templates->Surround`). Look for an example of `Surround with {}` there.

After that you'll be able to select the variable (probably <kbd>Ctrl+W</kbd>), then choosing your template (<kbd>Alt+T</kbd>) - keyboard only.

Comment: Thanks! searching a bit more on live templates, I found out that the shortcut soutv might be useful for printing variables

Answer (score 2):

Type:

`yourVarOrSmthng` <kbd>.</kbd> `sout` + <kbd>Tab</kbd>

Works in IntelliJ 2019.1.1